# How to achieve complete control of printing on print server

Tags: c#, .net, printing

windows 2008 r2 server is configured as a print server.around 150 ip printers have access to the server.

how can i restrict users from printing and only authorized users can print.

what approach should be used. can complete print control be achieved. .

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can control access to the printers. I am going to assume that since you have 150 printers attached to your print server that you are using Windows Active Directory. When you go into the printer properties on your print server you should have a security tab that will allow you to assign either groups or individual users to use the printer.